# How to load a webform via ajax inside custom JS?

Tags: 8, webforms

I'm trying to load a webform block via ajax.

Right now I have:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/form/contact-us',
    success: function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    },
    error: function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```

How do i get the form as a block and not by the full page/node?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following steps :

1. Create follow this [how to create contact form block](https://www.peacog.com/drupal-blog/placing-contact-form-block-drupal-8)
2. Create route for example `form/contact-us-block` :

**custom_module.routing.yml**

```
custom_module.get_contact_form_block:
  path: '/form/contact-us-block'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\custom_module\Controller\TutorialController::getContactFormBlock'
```

**getContactFormBlock Action in your controller**

```
public function getContactFormBlock() {
    //- Set your block id here
    $bid = 4;
    $block = \Drupal\block_content\Entity\BlockContent::load($bid);
    $build = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
      ->getViewBuilder('block_content')
      ->view($block);
    return render($build)->__toString();
  }
```

3. Get the block html in your Js.

```
    (function ($, Drupal) {
      $(document).ready(function ($) {
        $.ajax({
          url: 'form/contact-us-block',
          success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
          },
          error: function (error) {
            console.log(error);
          }
        });
      });
    })(jQuery, Drupal);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you check `/admin/structure/webform/config` you will find a Site-wide webform support library inclusion option.

[image: Site wise webform support library]

You will get the [dialogue-library](https://YOUR_WEBROOT/modules/contrib/webform/js/webform.dialog.js?v=8.9.12) of the webform will be loaded. You can use that or customize the code to meet your own need.

UPDATE:

Use `class='use-ajax'` might help you load webform in modal.